# How to make the text area in CodeMirror extension fit the entire screen?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

Is there a way to make the text area in CodeMirror extension fit the entire screen? I am using 0.32 version downloaded from https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/codemirror.aspx

Currently, I find that the text area has a height of 300px, and a lot of screen space goes unused.

[image]

Is there a setting or a CSS modification that will make the text area fit the entire screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently version 0.4 fixes the line height issue. See the [CodeMirror repository on GitHub](https://github.com/buildingblocks/tridion-mirror).

> **Changes in v0.4**
>
> Installation script
>
> Fix bug with height of Source tab being limited to 21 lines
>
> Integrate Dreamweaver suggestions from Jaime Santos Alcon (Press ctrl+space)

Answer (score 10):

What I have been doing lately is changing the CodeMirror css files themselves to get it to become larger.  In your extensions folder under `CodeMirror\CSS\codemirror.css` change the top 2 classes to the following:

```
.CodeMirror {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 100%;
  /* Necessary so the scrollbar can be absolutely positioned within the wrapper on Lion. */
  position: relative;
  /* This prevents unwanted scrollbars from showing up on the body and wrapper in IE. */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.CodeMirror-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /* This is needed to prevent an IE[67] bug where the scrolled content
     is visible outside of the scrolling box. */
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}
```

In explanation I changed the height of code-mirror and also the way in which its overflow works to support this extra functionality.  I have tested this in Chrome 43 and IE 11 with no bugs found so far.

Comment: Hey Nicholas, this seems to work well, is this more robust than the 0.4 update? If so, perhaps submit as an improvement too.

Comment: I took a look at the CSS of the 0.4 update and as it turns out, they are using the exact same CSS as I posted.